# Creating a button to clear/reset existing DTedit data table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I started using DTedit Package ('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.3.0' version) in my Shiny Application and it has been super handy and easy to create editable datatables.

I'm currently trying to create 'clear' or 'reset' Shiny Action Button to empty the DTEdit data table (when the user has already added data) but can't seem to get it to work!

I tried to "clear" the dataframe `mydata <<- mydata[0,]`(see below example `app.R` with slight modification from [DTEdit Example](https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit/blob/master/inst/template/app.R) but the data seems to still be persistent in the Shiny Table. It is only when I try to add a "New" data row Using the "New" DTedit button, it will then delete the previous records.

*Slight Modification from DTEdit Example app.R *

```
library(shiny)
library(DTedit)

##### Create the Shiny server
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- data.frame(name = character(),
                       email = character(),
                       useR = factor(levels = c('Yes', 'No')),
                       notes = character(),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  ##### Callback functions.
  my.insert.callback <- function(data, row) {
    # 'data' contains the dataframe *after* the row has been inserted/added
    # 'row' is the row number where data has been inserted
    mydata <<- rbind(mydata, data[row,])
    # in this case, 'mydata' should just be the same as 'data'
    return(mydata)
  }
  
  my.update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row) {
    # 'data' contains the dataframe *after* the row has been updated
    # 'row' is the row number where data has been updated
    # 'olddata' is the previous version of the data
    mydata[row,] <<- data[row,]
    # in this case, 'mydata' should just be the same as 'data'
    return(mydata)
  }
  
  my.delete.callback <- function(data, row) {
    # 'data' contains the dataframe *before* the row has been deleted
    # 'row' is the row number where data is to be deleted
    mydata <<- mydata[-row,]
    # in this case, 'mydata' should just be the same as data[-c(row),]
    return(mydata)
  }
  
  ##### Create the DTedit object
  test <- DTedit::dtedit(
    input, output,
    name = 'mycontacts',
    thedata = mydata,
    edit.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR', 'notes'),
    edit.label.cols = c(
      'Name', 'Email Address', 'Are they an R user?', 'Additional notes'
    ),
    input.types = c(notes = 'textAreaInput'),
    view.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR'),
    callback.update = my.update.callback,
    callback.insert = my.insert.callback,
    callback.delete = my.delete.callback)
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    mydata <<- mydata[0,]
  })
}


##### Create the shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('DTedit Template'),
  uiOutput('mycontacts'), 
  actionButton("reset", "Reset")
)

##### Start the shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but your code cannot work because the data object you supply to `dtedit`, namely `mydata`, is not reactive. Therefore `dtedit` is not aware of any change you do to this dataframe. You have to use a reactive dataframe.

```r
  DTdata <- reactiveVal(mydata)

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    dat <- DTdata()
    DTdata(dat[0, ])
  })

  ##### Create the DTedit object
  test <- DTedit::dtedit(
    input, output,
    name = 'mycontacts',
    thedata = DTdata(),
    edit.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR', 'notes'),
    edit.label.cols = c(
      'Name', 'Email Address', 'Are they an R user?', 'Additional notes'
    ),
    input.types = c(notes = 'textAreaInput'),
    view.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR'),
    callback.update = my.update.callback,
    callback.insert = my.insert.callback,
    callback.delete = my.delete.callback)
```